# ¿Por qué no continua la ejecución en la consola?

Tags: java

Verán, he hecho un programa sencillo en java usando el IDE de Eclipse, en el código fuente no me marca error.

```
package uuu;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UUU {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        System.out.print("Hola dime tu nombre");
        a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Mucho gusto en conocerte "+a);



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Y a la hora de ejecutarlo en la consola me sale lo siguiente:

```
Hola dime tu nombre
alda
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at uuu.UUU.main(UUU.java:9)
```

Comment: No puedes usar nextInt si vas a recibir una cadena de texto, prueba con nextLine

Comment: Además a debe ser String

Answer (score 6):

Como te han puesto en los comentarios, estas guardando una cadena de texto en una variable `int`. Esto no es correcto, para poder almacenar en este caso un nombre, tu variable `a` debe ser de tipo `String`. Después para poder capturar la cadena de texto, en vez de utilizar `input.nextInt()` debes utilizar `input.nextLine()`

**Código:**

```
package uuu;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UUU {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        System.out.print("Hola dime tu nombre");
        a=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Mucho gusto en conocerte "+a);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```